# Using Axis2/Java to generate code from WSDL

Tags: 10.04, java

I'm trying to use Axis2/Java to consume web services. In particular, I'm trying to generate Java skeleton code from a WSDL file.

I installed the libaxis-java package, but the package doesn't contain the WSDL2Java.sh script I was expecting. I tried to generate the Java code by doing:

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/axis.jar org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java foo.wsdl
```

But I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
        at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.class$(LogFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:45)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.getLogFactory(LogFactory.java:41)
        at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:33)
        at org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle.<clinit>(ProjectResourceBundle.java:53)
        at org.apache.axis.i18n.MessagesConstants.<clinit>(MessagesConstants.java:32)
        at org.apache.axis.utils.Messages.<clinit>(Messages.java:36)
        at org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java.<clinit>(WSDL2Java.java:112)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java. Program will exit.
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a jar on the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Riccardo Murri's answer, I was able to determine all the jar files required for the classpath:

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/axis.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-logging.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-logging-api.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-logging-adapters.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-discovery.jar:/usr/share/java/jaxrpc.jar:/usr/share/java/wsdl4j.jar org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java foo.wsdl
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be lacking the commons-logging jar in your classpath:

1. Install Ubuntu package `libcommons-logging-java`:

   sudo apt-get install libcommons-logging-java
2. Append `/usr/share/java/commons-logging.jar` and its relatives to your classpath:

   java -cp /usr/share/java/axis.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-logging.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-logging-api.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-logging-adapters.jar org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java foo.wsdl

It's quite likely that there will be other dependencies missing; you might want to use the [JarAnalyizer](http://www.kirkk.com/main/Main/JarAnalyzer) tool to find them and add to the classpath.